# monodevelop - working debug but not working release

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I have developed a project with VS on Windows 10. Right now on Linux mint i am debugging the project with MonoDevelop and it runs just fine.

Let me show you:

[image]

However when i make a build and i go to the Release folder and then i try from the terminal to launch the program i have a problem. Let me show you first the files i have build:

[image]

Then i go to the directory with my terminal and i run:

`chmod +x ./WorldServer.exe` then i run `./WorldServer.exe`

and i receive the following error:

[image]

I know that this is .exe file and maybe i have to build a different type of file. But i am not really sure what setting should i apply in my project to make a working build for linux.

As far as i know linux is using .so as extension for it's libraries. However it is generating .dll files. Can i change that? Can i somehow make my project to be "buildable" in the two OS Linux and Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells us, you need `System.Management` in your project. It isn't there.

#### Why?

Because Mono, [according to there Road-map](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/roadmap/), doesn't support this:

> The following do not map to operating systems other than Windows, and
>   we are unlikely to spend time to support them even on Windows:
>
> - System.Management

### How?

System.Management is a library that only works on Windows. The MySQL connector driver has started to depend on this library and tries to load it per reflection.

I'm not into this whole MySql Progess but there is an [open bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81973) for it. Also there is a comment which says:

> The last working version of the MySQL .NET Driver is 6.4.6

I hope this helps you.

Comment: So if i have MySQL in my project i can not make it work both linux and windows ?

Comment: And also why the project runs in debugging mode but in release it fails ?

Comment: It think, if you downgrade your MySQL Driver to 6.4.6 it's possible.

Comment: @TonyStark Debug and Release on the Linux machine and different behavior?

Comment: Yes the behaviour is different on debug and release. My question is why ?

Comment: @TonyStark mh... Could you provide the content of your `*.csproj` File from the project? It's a simple XML, which can be opened with every text editor.

Comment: No clue why it different behave right now. Did you use NUGET for adding the MySql Package? Try `Update-Package MySQL.Data.Entities -Version 6.4.4` for the downgrad.

Comment: I cleaned and runned again and now its working. However when i start the program here in linux i can not close it with "CTRL+C" like i do in Windows. Any idea about that ?

Comment: @TonyStark SIGHUP `Ctrl-Z` or SIGQUIT `Ctrl-\ `?